# Pandas aggregation warning with lambdas (FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/pandas-aggregation-warning-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with-renaming-is-depreca), however I do need renaming columns because I aggregate my data using functions:

```
def series(x):
    return ','.join(str(item) for item in x)

agg = {
    'revenue': ['sum', series],
    'roi': ['sum', series],
}

df.groupby('name').agg(agg)
```

As a result I have groups of identically named columns:

[image]

which become completely indistinguishable after I drop the higher column level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

[image]

So, how do I go about keeping unique names for my columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Is there a way to use something like 'droplevel' and in process, rename the the other level using the dropped level labels as prefix/suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405971/pandas-is-there-a-way-to-use-something-like-droplevel-and-in-process-rename)

Comment: and duplicate of [Pandas: use one column for groupby and get stats for multiple other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498118/pandas-use-one-column-for-groupby-and-get-stats-for-multiple-other-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` for `flatten` columns names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```